# Google Cloud Storage signing URLs - NodeJS

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage, signed

So I'm trying to sign URLs to use GCS in my app, following this : [signed urls](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/accesscontrol#Signed-URLs)

But I want to do it in NodeJS, and the signed code is given only in Java, Python, Go or C# : [signing code](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/accesscontrol#signing-code-python)

I failed to find a good resource on the internet to do the same thing in NodeJS. I will need to do it in Node because I'm using Node to listen to some event on another database and want to generate the urls accordingly.

Thanks for any help !